# How can I capture logs from .net WebHost in our own logger?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging

There is proopably some simple answer this but after trawling the internet for hours, I have not yet found an answer

We have our own implementation of a logging-system
We would like to capture the information logged in WebHost in our own logger
But how do I direct the logs produced in WebHost to our logger?

Our webhost is pretty standard, if that makes any difference
We are building to .net 5

```
        _host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .AddHttpListener(_startUpConfig)
            .UseHttpSys(options =>
            {
                options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate;
                options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = true;
                options.MaxConnections = -1;
                options.MaxAccepts = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2;
            })
            .UseUrls($"{_url}://+:{PortNo}/")
            .UseUnityServiceProvider(IocContainer)
            .ConfigureServices(services => { services.AddSingleton(_startUpConfig); })
            .UseStartup<StartUp>()
            .Build();
```

Comment: Does your logging-system supports filters?

Comment: No. Just log-level. I realize I propably have to wrap our logger in another object. Just not sure how

Comment: Why not use already existing logging framework available with filter? In your logger you need similar kind of feature to log entries to configured channel based on some values such as logger name or log source. Its not clear how's your logging solution implemented and it is used. I am sure the solution to your problem will not be that simple.

Comment: It would be preferable to log to our own logging-system which is integrated in to our DevOps etc. But ok. that could be a second choice. How do I grab those in a production environment where our service runs on a VM? Specifically I need to understand why some Kerberos tokens are rejected by the WebHost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trawling the internet even more, I finally came across the answer
Microsoft has actually nicely produced a document on how to add your own custom logger

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider

Pretty straight forward actually, as I expected.
Thank you Microsoft :-)